# Telerik Radgrid Access Values

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I want to access values of the insert form in Telerik radgrid. how can i do that this is what i am trying

```
 protected void RadGrid3_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.PerformInsertCommandName)
        {

            GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            string a = (editedItem.FindControl("ID") as TextBox).Text;
            string b = (editedItem.FindControl("Quantity") as TextBox).Text;


        }
 }
```

It throws me the following error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

When editing or inserting a grid item, you could access and modify the controls generated in the editable item (*reference Telerik documentation*).
Try something like this:

```
protected void RadGrid3_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
 {
   GridEditableItem editableItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
   string a= editableItem["Id"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
   string b= editableItem["Quantity"].Controls[0] as TextBox;

 }
}
```

Please note that I have not tested the the above snippet. For more references you can look [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html)

Comment: Have you tested the above snippet? Any result?